# How to thank your client who is showing interest in working in future?

Tags: word-choice

My client has just sent me this message - 
"Hey I heard you are leaving the company. I wish the best of luck and if you ever want to work for XXX or another project I may have just let me know"

How do I thank him?

I think of writing - Thanks for the **offer** or **opportunity** but it is neither offer nor opportunity at the moment.

What should I write?

Comment: The client just offered you an opportunity, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I would just say, after the general thank-yous etc.:

> 'Please feel free to contact me should an opportunity for further collaboration, in the future, come about. I look forward to working with you again."